# Doxygen indentation in markdown files

Tags: doxygen

I'm using doxygen to consume markdown files.  However, I'm running into an issue related to indentation.  Doxygen doesn't seem to recognize '>' for indentation.  I also don't want 4 spaces because I don't want code blocks.  I want subsections under high level heading to just be indented so it's easier to read for the audience and understand context.

Is it possible to indent paragraphs/line in markdown files for use in doxygen? (without making them code blocks)

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which output format do you need?

Comment: @albert I'm using doxygen v1.8.14.  All I'm looking for is that the selected text is indented.  Just like you would do for a paragraph in MS Word.

Comment: @albert Ok... I see that this is NOT a basic feature of markdown.  I assumed it was because one of my viewers presented it that way.  Basically, this feature doesn't exist in markdown without modifying the stylesheet.  I will try that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` character in the markdown syntax is reserved for the "blockquote" facility (see https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote). By doxygen's HTML output this is shown by means of a vertical bar and some indentation.
This style is defined by means of the doxygen.css, one can define one's own (`HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`) stylesheet withe e.g. the following code in it:

```
blockquote {
        border-left-width: 0px;
}
```

The default definition is:

```
blockquote {
        background-color: #F7F8FB;
        border-left: 2px solid #9CAFD4;
        margin: 0 24px 0 4px;
        padding: 0 12px 0 16px;
}
```

In a similar way one can adjust the background color etc.

Note: this will change all your blockquotes.

Comment: Are blockquotes used by doxygen in other areas (e.g. when extracting the code and creating the html)?  I don't want to mess up the normal doxygen generation.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge (and what I saw in the code) no it is only used for real blockquotes